# TypeScript stage 3 fields decorators

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, javascript-decorators

I'm currently trying to update a field decorator from experimental TypeScript to stage 3.
All it does is send a notification when the value of a field is updated.
The old implementation looks like this:

```
function watchChange<T extends Object>(target: T, key: keyof T & string) {
    console.log('Calling the watch change decorator')

    let property = target[key];
    const getter = ()=>{
        return property
    };
    const setter = (newVal: any) =>{
        console.log(`${key} changed from ${property} to ${newVal}`)
        property = newVal
    }

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true
    })
}
```

My current attempt to do the same with stage 3 decorators looks like this:

```
function watchChange<T, V>(target: any, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<T, V>) {

    return function(value: V) {
        const setter = (newVal: any) =>{
            console.log(`${context.name as string} changed from ${value} to ${newVal}`)
            this[context.name] = newVal
        }
        context.access.set = setter
        return value
    }

}
```

context.access.set requires one additional obj parameter. What is it? Currently the documentation is very scarce.
This doesn't work. Why and how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Object.defineProperty` in the `return init-func`, instead of modifying the context.